# WCF service in local network

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created and started WCF service on my development machine.

When I use `http://localhost:8080/ServiceName/Function` as URL, works fine.

When I use `http://MY.LAN.IP.ADDRESS:8080/ServiceName/Function` as URL, it is NOT working
anywhere, not on development machine not on other machines in LAN.

For example, in Android test app, the error message says:

> "Connection to http://... is refused"

I have disabled windows firewall and antivirus.

What is causing such problem?
Do I need to configure something in service configuration (web.config)?

Note that service is running inside ASP.Net Development Server.

Comment: Instance is hosted inside ASP.Net Development Server.

Comment: That isn't my question... Do you have a Windows Service on that server or through Internet Information System (IIS). The reason I ask, is because there are IIS settings that need to be implemented so when the address is used by outside traffic it is actually directed to your application.

Comment: No I do not have any of these

Comment: Is the service actually _running_ on the development server at the time of the request? The development server is really only meant to be used during debug.

Comment: Post your `app.config` and (if any), the code you're using to create the `ServiceHost`.

Comment: Yeah, we need your host information and configs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP.NET Development Server cannot accept remote connections, so this won't work from outside of local machine

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1242749.aspx/1) site, you should check to see if the random port that the Development Server chooses (which, in your case would be 8080) is open on the firewall. If that doesn't work, then I'm not sure that it will work at all without a version of IIS installed and configured for these remote requests.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you have it configured; as that can actually cause complications.  But your issue resides within your `Host`.  How your creating the `Host` to receive your `Proxies`.  One thing that may be happening:

When it runs on your local machine it actually is enabling `IIS Express` so you can view the service and test it.  So at that moment IIS is handling those request.  Which allows it to work without a problem.

The other dilemma are these:

- The Development Server may not be configured to receive outside request.
- IIS Server may not be configured to receive those request.
- Or it has created a random port usage; which is not accessible.

That is more then likely what is happening.  Since IIS is automatically handling it; one of those are more then likely not correct.

But until we see your `app.config` and `ServiceHost` code details we can't be for certain.